# Is there a way to force Oracle to evaluate the Filter after the Join Access?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle18c

I want to filter on the result of a join, using a cast. The problem is that part of the original field cannot be cast to an Integer. It would not be a problem if the filter was applied after the join. This is why I wonder if there's a way (perhaps an Optimizer Hint or something) to push the filter evaluation after the join operation.

This is a query that I built for the example. I would expect it to work, but fails with an 'ORA-01722 invalid number' :

```
WITH "literal" AS (
    SELECT 1 AS "literal_id", 'abc' AS "literal"
    FROM "DUAL"
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS "literal_id", '7' AS "literal"
    FROM "DUAL"
),
     "scalar" AS (
         SELECT 3 AS "scalar_id", 2 AS "literal_id"
         FROM "DUAL"
         CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 10000
     )
SELECT *
FROM "scalar"
         JOIN "literal" USING ("literal_id")
WHERE TO_NUMBER("literal") > 6;
```

The ORA-01722 is thrown because it's applied on the "literal" CTE, hence crashes because 'abc' is obviously not a number. 
We can see this in the execution plan :

[Query execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocoWL.png)

To reduce the possibilities around the cause of my problem, I executed that query:

```
CREATE TABLE "literal" AS (
    SELECT 1 AS "literal_id", 'abc' AS "literal"
    FROM "DUAL"
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS "literal_id", '7' AS "literal"
    FROM "DUAL"
);
CREATE TABLE "scalar" AS (
    SELECT 3 AS "scalar_id", 2 AS "literal_id"
    FROM "DUAL"
    CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 10000
);
CREATE TABLE "joined" AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM "scalar"
             JOIN "literal" USING ("literal_id")
);
SELECT *
FROM "joined"
WHERE TO_NUMBER("literal") > 6;
```

Which works perfectly fine.

So, is there a way to rewrite this query (I still need this to be a single query though) so it will not try to convert the 'abc' ?

For reference, I tried this on Oracle Database 18c Standard Edition 2 Release 18.0.0.0.0 as well as Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old school trick is to structure the query such that the predicate can't be pushed into the join.  If you put the join into an inline view and add a `rownum`, that'll prevent the optimizer from evaluating the predicate until the join is complete

```
WITH "literal" AS (
    SELECT 1 AS "literal_id", 'abc' AS "literal"
    FROM "DUAL"
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS "literal_id", '7' AS "literal"
    FROM "DUAL"
),
     "scalar" AS (
         SELECT 3 AS "scalar_id", 2 AS "literal_id"
         FROM "DUAL"
         CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 10000
     )
select *
  from (
SELECT "scalar_id",  "literal_id", "literal", rownum
FROM "scalar"
         JOIN "literal" USING ("literal_id")
)
WHERE TO_NUMBER("literal") > 6;
```

If you're on 12.2 or later, you have the ability to take advantage of enhancements to the `to_number` function to return a NULL if there is a conversion error.

```
WITH "literal" AS (
    SELECT 1 AS "literal_id", 'abc' AS "literal"
    FROM "DUAL"
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS "literal_id", '7' AS "literal"
    FROM "DUAL"
),
     "scalar" AS (
         SELECT 3 AS "scalar_id", 2 AS "literal_id"
         FROM "DUAL"
         CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 10000
     )
SELECT "scalar_id",  "literal_id", "literal"
FROM "scalar"
         JOIN "literal" USING ("literal_id")
WHERE to_number("literal" default null on conversion error) > 6;
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea of adding the rownum to the subquery so it’s forced to be evaluated first. 
Also, I haven’t noticed the « default null on version error » option. This method seems to be the more efficient, but I won’t be able to use it since one of our partners is still on 10g.

Answer (score 1):

For the `where`, use a conditional conversion.  For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM "scalar" s JOIN
     "literal" l
      USING ("literal_id")
WHERE (CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(l.literal, '[^[0-9]+$')
            THEN TO_NUMBER(l.literal)
       END) > 6;
```

As for your question, I don't think so.  Oracle has a pretty sophisticated optimizer, so it will rearrange operations to optimize performance.  You *could* use a CTE and a compiler hint to materialize the CTE, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although since this query will be executed on hundreds of million rows, I try to minimize those comparisons. Which is why I would prefer to trick the query planner.